# Trying to create new dataframe from another dataframe using info provided from csv file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with a list of strings:(The strings will change everyday)

-Bob

-John

-Frank

I have a  pandas dataframe

Header:Name age sex

-Shelly 56 Female

-Jim    48 Male

-Frank  50 Male

-John   52 Male

-Bob    53 Male

-Mary   40 Female

I would like to go through each name in the csv file and retrieve the matching row and create a new dataframe.

Comment: a pandas DataFrame or what kind of data frame?

Comment: Yeah sorry a pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv
import pandas as pd

frame = pd.DataFrame({
    'Names': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    'Ages': [22, 33, 44, 55],
    'Gender': ['M', 'M', 'F', 'F']
})

names = []

pf = open("test.csv")
csv_reader = csv.reader(pf)

for row in csv_reader:
    names.append(row[0])

new_frame = frame.loc[frame['Names'].isin(names)]

print(new_frame)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I was headed in the right path just missed a few things.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to keep the order from the list and not the dataframe? I am trying to get to a point to compare rows(order dictated by the csv file) For example I would like to compare Bob to John.

Comment: @Bodom I'm not sure that I get it. I think it's best if you submit another stackoverflow question with this or if it's too much trouble I can help you out in private (just check my email on my profile page).